# Store WPF ListView Values/Items into Database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, listview

I have Wpf LisView As show in the [ListView Categories IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqZkA.jpg)

Now, i'm having Challenge saving the items/values Of the ListView into the Database, This is the code i used for saving the Items.

```
SelectedCategory sc = new SelectedCategory();
SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("  Data Source=database.sqlite; Version=3; Compress=True; ");
con.Open();
string query = " INSERT INTO income_details (name, amount)  VALUES (@1, @2) ";
for (int i = 0; i < ListView_Selected_Category.Items.Count; i++)
{
     SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@1", ListView_Selected_Category.Items[0]));
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@2", ListView_Selected_Category.Items[0]));
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
MessageBox.Show("Saved");
con.Close();
```

Cause i cant get the ListView Column.

Please i really need help, Thanks In advance.

Comment: What's the problem? did you get any error message?

Comment: Are you sure you didnt mean DataGrid? As for ListView, you need to get underlying colelction of objects (ItemsSource) and there should be binded field "Selected" or something like that

Answer (score 0):

If you have Correctly implemented the MVVM patten then you will have your ListView reading from a model of POCO objects(most likely from Entity frame work already with the database connection defined) via a viewmodel

ie

ListView ItemSource="{Binding List}" />

where binding points to an ObservableCollection called List

and the save action is something like this

```
public void Save_Click(object sender, eventargs args)
{
    foreach(var item in List.Where(vm=>vm.IsSelected))
    {
        item.Save();
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
}
```

and ViewModel is something like this

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Model Model{get;set;}
    public bool IsSelected{get;set;}
    public int Val1{get;set;}
    public string Val2{get;set;}
    public void Save()
    {
        //Copy ViewModel to Model and trigger Save Logic
    }
    public void Cancel() //allows undoing
    {
        //Copy Model to ViewModel
    }
}
```

then if you are doing it manually without EF or something else

```
public class Model
{
    public int Val1{get;set;}
    public string Val2{get;set;}

    public void Save()
    {
        SelectedCategory sc = new SelectedCategory();
        using(SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("  Data Source=database.sqlite; Version=3; Compress=True; "))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = " INSERT INTO income_details (name, amount)  VALUES (@1, @2) ";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@1", Val1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@2", Val2);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
)
```

note: you could also change it to a static function and pass in multiple models if you want to use the connection many times